# In AJAX url how to get the parameter values to php varibles?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

By using the ajax script I am creating the table.

```
table = table_to_use.DataTable({

  ajax: {
    url: "example.php?getvalues",
    dataSrc: ""
   },
```

Below mentioned code from PHP server-side.

```
if (isset($_GET["getvalues"])) {

$sql = setupSql();
$query = "SELECT * FROM testing WHERE expiration > NOW()";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "[";
echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    echo "," . json_encode($row);
echo "]";
//$queue_data = listQueue();

//echo $queue_data;
return;
}
```

My question is, In url i am passing parameter values how can Get that parameter values?

```
URL:**example.php?id=1243&status=queued**
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `url: "example.php?getvalues",` does not have any value does it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get your id value from this url (example.php?id=1243&status=queued) as

```
$_GET['id']
```

and status value as

```
$_GET['status'].
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach on the $_GET array

```
foreach($_GET as $key=> $value) {

echo $key.' : '.$value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` Global variables of PHP. You can access the URL parameters.

**Example :**

**Url :** `example.php?id=1243&status=queued`

```
// Returns 1243.
$id = $_GET['id'];

// Returns queued.
$status = $_GET['status'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In ajax :

```
ajax: {
        url: "example.php?getvalues",
        dataSrc: "",
        method: GET
    },
```

and for the 
**Url : example.php?id=1243&status=queued**

USE :

```
// Returns 1243.
$id = $_GET['id'];

// Returns queued.
$status = $_GET['status'];
```

to get the values from URL of `id and status` parameter.